# standardizing prompts across shells in cygwin

Tags: cygwin, sh, ksh, prompt, .profile

I'm having a heck of a time standardizing my prompts across the different shells I have installed for **cygwin**.

Installed shells:

1. **bash** (default login shell)
2. **sh**
3. **csh** (**tcsh**, actually)
4. **ksh**
5. **zsh**

My prompt is standardized across **bash**, **csh**, and **zsh**, but I can't get **sh** and **ksh** on board.

The prompt I'm looking to use across all shells is similar to the following:

```
20121216 15:18:04 [shell]   # date and time in yellow, shell in red
user@hostname pwd           # user@host in green, pwd in yellow
$                           # white
```

I've got it set the way I want it for **bash** with the following line in `/etc/profile`:

```
PS1="\[\e]0;\w\a\]\n\[\e[33m\]\D{%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S} \[\e[31m\][bash]\n\[\e[32m\]\u@\h \[\e[33m\]\w\[\e[0m\]\n\$ "
```

And I've got it set for **csh** with the following line in `.tcshrc`:

```
set prompt="\n%{\033[33m%}%Y%W%D %P %{\033[31m%}[csh]\n%{\033[32m%}%n@%M %{\033[33m%}%~\n%{\033[0m%}$ "
```

And I've got it set for **zsh** with the following lines in `.zshrc`:

```
PROMPT="
%{$fg[yellow]%}%D{%Y%m%d} %* %{$fg[red]%}[zsh]%{$reset_color%}
%{$fg[green]%}%n@%m %{$reset_color%}%{$fg[yellow]%}%~%{$reset_color%}
$ "
```

But I can't seem to set a default prompt for **sh** or **ksh** anywhere.  I can open both of them and manually set `PS1="$ "`, but I cannot for the life of me get it to set automatically.  The **sh** prompt looks identical to the **bash** prompt, and the **ksh** prompt is gibberish (bc it doesn't like the syntax of PS1 that it's inheriting from **bash**, I assume).

Things I've tried unsuccessfully:

- setting PS1 in `/etc/profile` (in a case statement reading the shell
  name from `echo $0`)
- setting PS1 in `.kshrc`
- setting PS1 in `.shrc`
- setting PS1 in `.sh_profile`
- setting PS1 in `.profile`

It seems that **cygwin** just doesn't execute the files listed above when I launch one of those shells.  Note that I only ever launch those shells from within **bash**.

Any ideas?  (Sorry for the book, I'm just trying to be thorough.)

Comment: There's no such thing as `'sh'` anymore.  It used to refer to the original Bourne Shell, but nowadays is linked to some other minimal feature shell  like `ash`, `bash`, or `dash`.  It does not have the features you need - you can try and set PS1 from another shell, but it won't track the time, nor the shell's working directory.

Comment: `ksh` can track the current directory with `PS1='$PWD $ '` -- use single quotes to postpone expansion of `$PWD` until `$PS1` gets evaluated.  The original documentation for `ksh` has a hack for adding date and time, but it's still a (smart) hack.  The bash escape sequences won't help here.

Comment: Thanks for that info, Henk.  But I guess what I was really asking is where do I set the default prompt in `ksh`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official Korn shell *ksh93* will read /etc/profile and ~/.profile on login, in that order.

If `ksh` is not acting as a login shell it will try to read the file referred to by `$ENV`, or `$HOME/.kshrc` if `ENV` is not set.

Older versions (sun's *ksh88* in particular) suffered from a chicken and egg situation because you could only set `ENV` *in* `~/.profile`, but then you still had to source the file yourself with `. $ENV`.

Note that `ENV` and `PS1` have to be exported in order to be picked up by ksh instances spawned after login (say, from `screen` or `tmux`).

Comment: +1 and acceptance for a) the reference to `$ENV` and b) the info about `sh` in your earlier comment.  together, that led me to add `export ENV=$HOME/.kshrc` to my `/etc/profile`, then add `export PS1=blahblahblah` to ~/.kshrc, which is finally setting a default prompt for non-login korn shells.  thanks!